# Can a border/stroke be added to a Raphael image?

Tags: javascript, css, image, raphael

I am trying to add a border, stroke, or drop shadow to a Raphael image element. My ultimate goal is to have an animated glowing border. I have [achieved this on standard HTML elements](http://jsfiddle.net/7qA6f/1/) using JavaScript, but I am unable to find a way to do it using Raphael.

I have read posts that suggest using a rect with an image fill, but this won't work because I need the images to be scalable. I have not found a way to set the dimensions of the image fill.

Is there a way to access a Raphael.image element's style attributes using JavaScript?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try **glow** in RaphaleJS ?

http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.glow

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: Is there a way to animate it?  I'm not sure how to use glow with animate.

Answer (score 1):

I would use that code to animate the glow:

```
Obj.animate({opacity:0},1000);
Obj.glow(properties);
Obj.animate({opacity:1},1000);
```

Good luck